# Java print statement not printing all variables

Tags: java

I am trying to print some data from a text file, data in file would be something like this

user1.txt

```
1,1412.0  
2,345.0  
3,500.0  
4,234.0  
5
```

**As somebody saying the text file may contain \r ** i will provide link for my user1.txt file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aLCFQhduyt2e3VuBSgR-KJyKgmlz5gO0/view?usp=sharing

Code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // write your code here
        File f = new File("D:\\Fit\\user1.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        Scanner csc = new Scanner(f);
        sc.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
        while (sc.hasNext()){
           String d= sc.next();
           try {                                //I only need to print upto 4,234.0 so using a try block
               String c = sc.next();            //to skip the last line in text file which is "5"          
               System.out.println("Day"+d+":"+c+" cal");
           }
           catch (Exception e){
               break;
           }
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is, the output that i need

```
Day1:1412.0 cal  
Day2:345.0 cal  
Day3:500.0 cal  
Day4:234.0 cal
```

But the output it gives is

```
 cal    
 cal    
 cal    
 cal    
 cal
```

If i used `System.out.println("Day"+d+":"+c);` it gives the output as normal like
output:

```
Day1:1412.0    
Day2:345.0    
Day3:500.0    
Day4:234.0
```

I dunno why it only prints "cal" if I used `System.out.println("Day"+d+":"+c+" cal")`

Comment: I *suspect* that `c` contains a carriage return... I'd advise you to run the code in a debugger to check.

Comment: I am using catch statement to skip the last line of my data file

Comment: Looks like you have an "\r" in front of your "\n". This is why your text gets overridden.
Basically as @Jon Skeet said :)

Comment: Since you seem to be reading whole lines from the file, wouldn't `nextLine()` be a possibility to use (the while should then trigger on `hasNextLine()` of course)?
EDIT: You would need to split a line on the comma still then though.

Comment: "\r" in user1.txt file?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian i am trying to separate the data in a single line to two different data using a delimiter

Comment: @AnimeGeeker Yes, I got that much. The problem is most likely what everybody has written above though. You probably got a `\r` there as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have attached my txt file, there is no\r in my file though

Comment: @DanielBarbarian you can check my user1.txt file

Comment: I have provided gdrive link for it

Comment: By the way, `catch (Exception e) { break; }` is a very bad habit: you are quietly discarding any exception. If an exception is thrown, you want to *know* what happened.

Comment: @MCEmperor noo, the exception(java.util.NoSuchElementException) will be thrown everytime that's my logic to skip the last line of my data file.

Comment: MC Emperors' point is that you should generally avoid using exceptions for controlling flow.  Scanner has various has**() methods to inspect the stream for additional contents which may be leveraged for this purpose.  Consider using those for determining when you have reached the end of the data.

Comment: @user15793316 ya, I just now realized Windows text files have lines terminated by \r\n. from the answers, thanks:)

Comment: Exactly what vsfDawg says. Don't use exceptions for control flow. Use them for exceptional application state (often an error condition, e.g. file not found, connection failed, et cetera).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `String c = sc.next();` to `String c = sc.nextLine().substring(1);` 
you will get output:

```
Day1:1412.0 cal
Day2:345.0 cal
Day3:500.0 cal
Day4:234.0 cal
```

Comment: I got it thanks,but may i know what's the problem in my previous code?

Comment: I think this is just working around a bug.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have observed, it's almost certainly a \r problem.

The OP is running on Windows.

Windows text files have lines terminated by \r\n.

The program specifies delimiters that do not include \r.

```
sc.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
```

That delimiter pattern is where the bug lives.

The cure: include all whitespace in the delimiter pattern

```
sc.useDelimiter("\s+|,");
```

meaning "any string of whitespace, or a comma".  Alternatively,

```
sc.useDelimiter("\r?\n|,");
```

meaning "optional return followed by a linefeed, or a comma".

Comment: Oh now i get what the problem was tq very much